# need an example of an open set $V$ and a holomorphic function $f$ on $V$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

I need an example of an open set $V$ and  a holomorphic function $f$ on $V$ such that  $f^{'}(z)=0$ for each $z\in V$, but  $f$ is not constant.

Comment: What have  you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: you are right, I am so sorry. I was confused another question an  I was hurried up. @NoahSchweber

Answer (score 2):

You can take your open set to be two disjoint balls. Then set $f$ equal to $0$ in one of them and equal to $1$ in the other one.

Comment: oh, you are right. So sorry for this question.